# Get user data with Rest API in Flutter

Tags: rest, api, flutter, dart

I created a function using rest API to get one user data:

code:

```
  Future<User> getUser(int id) async{
    final response = await client.get('$baseUrl/user/$id');
    if(response.statusCode == 200){
      return userFromJson(response.body);
    }else return null;
  }
```

I must get data from user which is current logged in to this sytem, so I get his `id` from response with using `sharedPreferences`:

```
sharedPreferences.setInt("id", jsonResponse['id']);
```

but i don't know how to create an `FutureBuilder` which
would insert the appropriate id into my rest api function,

I try this:

```
class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  BuildContext context;
  ApiService apiService;
  SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    apiService = ApiService();
  }

  checkStorageStatus() async {
    sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    this.context = context;
    return SafeArea(
      child: FutureBuilder(
        future: apiService.getProfiles(), //I DON'T KNOW HOW TO PUT ID INTO THI FUNCTION
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Profile>> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Center(
              child: Text(
                  "Something wrong with message: ${snapshot.error.toString()}"),
            );
          } else if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
            User user = snapshot.data;
            return _buildListView(user);
          } else {
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

but i can't put my ID into `apiService.getProfiles()` function,
can anybody help me?

thanks for any help :)

Comment: You can call getUser(userId) method in initState of your page and get user data.Also share apiService.getProfiles() method definition.If you want to post data in your database you don't need futurebuilder you can just call future method.

Comment: @HaroonAshrafAwan can you show an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `apiService.getProfiles()` you get the id from SharedPreferences before performing your API request

```
getProfiles(){
  SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  int id = sharedPreferences.getInt("id");
  // perform http request to get UserProfile
}
```

Comment: thanks, i have one more question, how i can use ```sharedPreferences``` and my rest api function in one future builder?, i want to get one data from sharedPreferences and another from rest api

Comment: you should create another function that has both `SharedPrefs` and `Rest API calls` then call this function on you `FutureBuilder`

Answer (score 1):

```
class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  BuildContext context;
  ApiService apiService;
  SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    apiService = ApiService();
    fetchUser();
  }

  Future<List<Profile>> fetchUser() async {
    sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    int id = sharedPreferences.getInt("id");
    final response = await client.get('$baseUrl/user/$id');
    if(response.statusCode == 200){
      return userFromJson(response.body);
    }else return null;
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    this.context = context;
    return SafeArea(
      child: FutureBuilder(
        future: fetchUser(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Profile>> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Center(
              child: Text(
                  "Something wrong with message: ${snapshot.error.toString()}"),
            );
          } else if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
            User user = snapshot.data;
            return _buildListView(user);
          } else {
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks, i have one more question, how i can use ```sharedPreferences``` and my rest api function in one future builder?, i want to get one data from sharedPreferences and another from rest api